# Would a US student visa refusal affect my UK Tier 4 visa application?

Tags: united-kingdom

I have a fully funded phd position in UK and I want to apply for UK Tier 4 visa.However I have been rejected for US student visa 5 years ago and after that I continued my studies in Europe. I wonder if I should mention my US visa rejection in my UK visa application? If yes will this rejection affect visa result? (I also got a canadian student visa after my US visa rejection which I didn't use and prefered to came to EU)

Comment: Be truthful in your application and reveal anything they ASK for. Typically the USA and UK considers your entire immigration history however speaking from experience barring some fraud or something similarly unsavory in your background, a full funded student position is usually viewed very favorably. Nineteen years ago I was in a similar situation as yours, My previous refusal which was a year prior didn't even come up.

Comment: Everything affects a T4 application, but generally they work downward in your history so having a student status in the EEA will help. And not mentioning your US history will attract a P320 refusal and then matters will be immeasurably worse.